# Как получить записи, начинающиеся с определенных символов?

Tags: url, api, rest

Вопрос по Rest Api. Получаю данные через url - url вида

```
http://server/db/table/?filter_field=value
```

Возвращает все как надо. Проблема в том, что 
**value**
 содержит некий номер и буквенное обозначение региона такого вида:

> QWE123123123RU
>
> QWE123123123KZ

Как можно получить записи, начинающиеся с **QWE123123123**?

Comment: intval должен обрезать все после первого НЕцифрового символа (в php).

Comment: @Автостопом_до_Рая, "REST API" не подразумевает наличие каких-то конкретных фильтров. Либо они есть и отражены в документации, либо их над имплементировать вручную.

Comment: @Etki, Остается получать все записи, а потом выбирать те, которые необходимы?